# Live Admob ads will not load

Tags: android, admob

I'm having an issue trying to display live ads from Admob. The test ads were working fine but when I switched to the live Ads I keep getting this error

```
 Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
 The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly
```

I have followed the documentation provided by Admob and checked the APP_ID and still keep getting this error. I cant seem to figure out what the issue is. I have posted my code below, any suggestions?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.whatsfor">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-123123123123-43434323"/>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AdView bannerAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    bannerAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    bannerAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }}
```

activity.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6969696969/123123123"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must place the App ID `<meta-data>` under the `<application>` not under `<activity>`.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-123123123123-43434323"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Or, [the Official document](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml) mentions:

> Important: This step is required as of Google Mobile Ads SDK version
>   17.0.0. Failure to add this  tag results in a crash with the message: **The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly.**